# SQL Server case-sensitive collation at column level settings

Tags: sql-server

We have database collation as case-insensitive, but we need the data in the column to be stored and while query search to be as case sensitive.

Is there any property/settings available in SQL Server that whenever we create a table, the collation of column should automatically overwrite the database collation?

I know that we have to change collation at column level manually but any property/setting/query that we can use to change collation to case sensitive without any manual intervention.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-ver15
it is stated "You can override the database collation for char, varchar, text, nchar, nvarchar, and ntext data by specifying a different collation for a specific column of a table and using one of the following:"
Looks like you need to do it by hands